# Where does git fetch from when doing a git submodule update?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote, git-fetch

The `git submodule update` documentation says:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules, **fetching missing commits in submodules** and updating the working tree of the submodules.

But I can't find anything about from which remote git will fetch from. I was hoping to find some configuration, which would define the remote to fetch from.

My setup right now is: I have two remotes defined in one of my submodules. When doing a `git submodule update` I get following error:

```
fatal: --stdin can only be used when fetching from one remote
```

This sounds like git is trying to fetch from all known remotes. Is there a way to configure the remote fetch from?

Worth mentioning: none of the submodule's remotes is named `origin` (I really hope that is not the issue here)

Comment: `git submodule update` should (I *think*) use the remote from the configured branch, if there is a configured branch. Failing that, it should use the default remote, which is normally `origin`. The lack of an `origin` probably *is* the issue here.

Comment: I confirm that the code falls back to `origin` if the submodule is in detached HEAD or if the currently checked out branch does not have a configured upstream branch. Can’t link to the code right now as I’m on mobile but it’s easy to check in `git-submodule.sh` and `builtin/submodule--helper.c`. I agree it’s unfortunate that this can’t be configured. It’s on my todo list to improve that someday.